# Angular fillter not working when using date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular script does not seem to work

```
<td title="'Date'" filter="{ dateAdded: 'text'}" sortable="'dateAdded'"headerclass="'bg-table-header-primary'" style="text-align:center;">{{ item.dateAdded | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</td>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is your issue?

Comment: I edited my question. The | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' does not seem to work for me @Mistalis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, there are attributes that have single quotes (`'`) inside the double quotes (`"`).

Try to remove the single quotes (`'`).